# use ko.computed with if statement to set object observable property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Just got started with knockout and javascript. I'm stuck at setting the object monthData's mPrice value.

```
function monthData(mYear, mMonth, mSS, mMs, mLimit, mPerItem, mStartingPrice) {
    var self = this;
    self.mYear= mYear;
    self.mMonth = mMonth;
    self.mSs = mSS;
    self.mMs = mMs;
    self.mTotal = mSS + mMs;
    self.mLimit = mLimit;
    self.mPerItem = mPerItem;
    self.mStartingPrice = mStartingPrice;
};
```

This is were it stops working. if I set self.mPrice = 0 i get all the months printed out atleast.

```
 self.mPrice = ko.computed(function() {
    var limit = self.mLimit;
    var perItem = self.mPerItem;
    var startingPrice = self.mStartingPrice;
    var total = self.mTotal;
    if (total <= limit) {
        return startingPrice;
    } else {
    var aboveLimit = total - limit;
    var extra = aboveLimit * perItem;
    return startingPrice + extra;
    }
});

}

function statViewModel() {
this.tak = ko.observable(100);
this.styckpris = ko.observable(10);
this.grundpris = ko.observable(500);
var self = this;

// testing with some months
self.allMonths = ko.observableArray([
    new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, this.tak, this.styckpris, this.grundpris),
    new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, this.tak, this.styckpris, this.grundpris),
    new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, this.tak, this.styckpris, this.grundpris),
    new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, this.tak, this.styckpris, this.grundpris),
    new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, this.tak, this.styckpris, this.grundpris)       
]);    
}
```

-Edit:
Just after I posted I found a missing paranteses. Now I get it to print out but it says:

```
function d(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!d.equalityComparer||!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return this}b.r.Va(d);return c}NaN
```

Html:

```
<p>Tak: <input data-bind="value: tak" /></p>
<p>Styckpris: <input data-bind="value: styckpris" /></p>
<p>Grundpris: <input data-bind="value: grundpris" /></p>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>År</th><th>Månad</th><th>SS</th><th>MS</th><th>Total</th><th>Pris</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: allMonths">
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: mYear"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: mMonth"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: mSs"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: mMs"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: mTotal"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: mPrice"></span></td>        
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your html code, you are also missing a set of parentheses there...

Comment: The problem isn't with the html but sure

Comment: Please see my 2nd answer. The 1st answer, I admit, was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ignore my other answer. I was getting confused between the code in your original question and the answer you posted. And so my explanation was unclear. So here I am going to answer your **question**, and not using anything from your **answer**.

The error you were receiving

```
function d(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!d.equalityComparer||!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return this}b.r.Va(d);return c}NaN
```

Can be simplified to

```
<ko.observable>NaN
```

And can be read as: "An observable is not a number"

This is an indication that you are trying to perform math operations to an observable.

In your `if` statement, you have: `if(total <= limit)`. You cannot compare if a number (`total`) is less than or equal to (`<=`) an observable (`limit`). You must get the value of limit by calling it like a function.

Your computed should now look like this:

```
self.mPrice = ko.computed(function() {
    var limit = self.mLimit();
    var perItem = self.mPerItem();
    var startingPrice = self.mStartingPrice();
    var total = self.mTotal;
    if (total <= limit) {
        return startingPrice;
    } else {
        var aboveLimit = total - limit;
        var extra = aboveLimit * perItem;
        return startingPrice + extra;
    }
});
```

Only the first 3 lines need changing - minor changes at that. Nothing else.

Comment: Thanx for all your help Sethi. If you check my answer below and the jsFiddle I posted it is now working. I'm an intern at a company and the knockout expert came and showed me the solution in 3 minutes :) Your answer is correct though and I will give you the accepted answer for all your help! (btw this is how he showed me to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/2BxVk/5/)

Answer (score 3):

Using an `observableArray` only 'asks' knockout to 'observe' the array functionality - i.e. `push`ing, removing, moving items, etc...

To 'ask' knockout to observe objects within that array, you actually want it to observe an objects particular properties.

So, your `monthData` object should declare `observable`s instead of regular/primitive properties:

```
function monthData(mYear, mMonth, mSS, mMs, mLimit, mPerItem, mStartingPrice) {

    var self = this;
    self.mYear = mYear;
    self.mMonth = mMonth;
    self.mSs = mSS;
    self.mMs = mMs;
    self.mTotal = ko.observable( mSS + mMs );
    self.mLimit = ko.observable( mLimit );
    self.mPerItem = ko.observable( mPerItem );
    self.mStartingPrice = ko.observable( mStartingPrice );

    ...

}
```

Note, I have only chosen the last 4 to be `observable`s because those are the properties you used in your `computed`. Now that they are `observable` the `computed` will know to reevaluate when any of them change.

Also, if you expect `self.mTotal` to auto-update (i.e. if you expect `self.mSs` or `self.mSm` to change), that will need to be a `computed` not an `observable`.

**EDIT:**

Don't forget to append any references to these variables with `()`. Your computed should now look like:

```
self.mPrice = ko.computed(function() {
    var limit = self.mLimit();
    var perItem = self.mPerItem();
    var startingPrice = self.mStartingPrice();
    var total = self.mTotal();
    if (total <= limit) {
        return startingPrice;
    } else {
        var aboveLimit = total - limit;
        var extra = aboveLimit * perItem;
        return startingPrice + extra;
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

Apologies for not reading the question properly.

I didn't realise you were passing in `tak`, `styckpris` and `grundpris` - my brain may have switched off when it saw a different language :p

**THE PROBLEM**

So what you have done when passing in these to your `monthData` constructor is **dereference** them. You have passed the value behind the observable rather than passing the observable. By passing the value, your `monthData` constructor, and thus your `mPrice` computed, will have no way of seeing changes to the observable.

**THE SOLUTION**

Pass the observables into your constructor without dereferencing them.

```
function monthData(mYear, mMonth, mSS, mMs, mLimit, mPerItem, mStartingPrice) {

    var self = this;
    self.mYear= mYear;
    self.mMonth = mMonth;
    self.mSs = mSS;
    self.mMs = mMs;
    self.mTotal = mSS + mMs;

    /* Remember that these are observable! */
    self.mLimit = mLimit;
    self.mPerItem = mPerItem;
    self.mStartingPrice = mStartingPrice;

    self.mPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        /* So, remember to dereference them! */
        var limit = self.mLimit();
        var perItem = self.mPerItem();
        var startingPrice = self.mStartingPrice();
        var total = self.mTotal;
        if (total <= limit) {
            return startingPrice;
        } else {
            var aboveLimit = total - limit;
            var extra = aboveLimit * perItem;
            return startingPrice + extra;
        }
    });

}

function statViewModel() {

    this.tak = ko.observable(100);
    this.styckpris = ko.observable(10);
    this.grundpris = ko.observable(500);
    var self = this;

    // testing with some months
    self.allMonths = ko.observableArray([
        new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, this.tak, this.styckpris, this.grundpris),
        new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, this.tak, this.styckpris, this.grundpris),
        new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, this.tak, this.styckpris, this.grundpris),
        new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, this.tak, this.styckpris, this.grundpris),
        new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, this.tak, this.styckpris, this.grundpris)       
    ]);    

}
```

Comment: mSs and mMs will not be changing. I only want the mPrice to change depending on the 3 different inputs. When I tried your suggestion I got this error: function d(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!d.equalityComparer||!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return this}b.r.Va(d);return c}NaN

Comment: I'm assuming that is just some portion of the minified knockout source. Don't forget, you have now made these variables observables - so look around where you're referencing them and ensure your call them like a function e.g. `self.mTotal()` not `self.mTotal`. I'll update my answer with what your computed should look like now

Comment: but total is not supposed to be observable. I will be retrieving SS and MS from a database, the total for each month will always be SS+MS. the only thing I want changed is mPrice and that should change based on the 3 input feilds. Here is my jsFiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/Ab9LG/

Comment: very long-winded way but we finally got there. you were very close when you wrote your question. I think your answer below threw me off what you were trying to accomplish. Please take a look at my 2nd edit: it should all work now :)

Answer (score 2):

Edit- this is now working as I wanted

```
function monthData(mYear, mMonth, mSS, mMs, parent) {
var self = this;
self.mYear = mYear;
self.mMonth = mMonth;
self.mSs = mSS;
self.mMs = mMs;
self.mTotal = mSS + mMs;

self.mPrice = ko.computed(function () {
    var limit = parent.tak();
    var perItem = parent.styckpris();
    var startingPrice = parent.grundpris();
    var total = self.mTotal;
    if (total <= limit) {
        return startingPrice;
    } else {
        var aboveLimit = total - limit;
        var extra = aboveLimit * perItem;
        var sum = parseInt(startingPrice) + parseInt(extra);
        return sum;
    }
});
}

function statViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.tak = ko.observable(100);
self.styckpris = ko.observable(10);
self.grundpris = ko.observable(500);

// testing with some months
self.allMonths = ko.observableArray([
new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, self),
new monthData(2013, 2, 112, 642, self),              
new monthData(2013, 2, 100, 742, self),
new monthData(2013, 3, 6513, 69, self),
new monthData(2013, 4, 34, 211, self),
new monthData(2013, 5, 123, 435, self),
new monthData(2013, 6, 412, 142, self),
new monthData(2013, 7, 412, 142, self)

]);
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new statViewModel());
```

Comment: please see my answer below, to address your new issue

Comment: thnx for the answer but the problem still remains :(

Comment: The knockout expert we have here finally came and took a look. This is  working now: http://jsfiddle.net/2BxVk/5/